# Pod to pod communication in kubernetes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, kubernetes

The application I use is deployed on kubernetes with a frontend (React) and multiple back end services (Express.js). I need my frontend to make fetch api calls to each service. The frontend and each service is deployed within its own pods. A service is exposing each pod so I have cluster-ip for each of these. The frontend was exposed using a load balancer so I have the external ip.

The question:
What would my fetch call need to be to access one of these services? (ex. fetch();)
Am I missing anything to make this possible?
I've looked through K8s docs and I couldn't understand what to do.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you see this kubernetes documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/#objectives?

Answer (score 0):

The Pods in the frontend Deployment run an  image that is configured to find the specific backend Service.
The key to connecting a frontend to a backend is the backend Service. A Service creates a persistent IP address and DNS name entry so that the backend microservice can always be reached. A Service uses [selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) to find the Pods that it routes traffic to.

The frontend connects to the backend worker Pods by using the DNS name given to the backend Service. The DNS name is for example "hello", which is the value of the  `name`  field in the preceding Service configuration file.

External IP can be used to interact with the  `frontend`  service from outside the cluster.
When the frontend and backends are now connected. You can hit the endpoint by using the curl command on the external IP of your frontend Service.

```sh
curl http://${EXTERNAL_IP}
```

Follow instruction from here: [frontend-backed-connection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/#objectives).

Please take a look:  [multiple-backend-kubernetes](https://medium.com/swlh/serving-multi-backend-application-on-http-s-load-balancer-with-ingress-on-gke-48322661391b), [frontend-backend-connection](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/connecting-apps/connecting-frontend-backend/), [kubernetes-services](https://blogs.cisco.com/developer/kubernetes-intro-3).